# regex's multi-match?

Tags: java, python, regex

Text : "aaaa"

Pattern : "aa"

then will two match: aa(0,1), aa(2,3)

if I want three match : aa(0,1), aa(1,2), aa(2,3).  (I believe this is a classical problem I don't know how to describe this :'(  )

How can I do it in java or python or others?

Comment: you should try something around java.util.regex using a Pattern and a matcher. Try first, show what your tried. It's a 4 line problem, google might help.

Comment: you are right. I'm silly. I misunderstand the Matcher class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code here:

```
String str = "aaaa";
Pattern p1= Pattern.compile("(aa)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
int start = -1;
while(matcher.find(start + 1)) {
    start = matcher.start(0);
    System.out.println("Found: " + start);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Found: 0
Found: 1
Found: 2
```

This is basically how you manipulate from where to search the next match in java. Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) and a lookahead assertion:

```
s = 'aaaa'
import re
matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(a{2}))', s)
results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
# -> ['aa', 'aa', 'aa']
```